# Use cached array length, RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript

```
// quickSort
function quickSort(arr) {
   let len = arr.length;
   if(len <= 1) return arr;
   let idx = Math.floor(len / 2);
   let middleValue = arr.splice(idx, 1)[0];
   let left = [];
   let right =[];
   for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       if(arr[i] < middleValue) {
           left.push(arr[i])
       } else {
           right.push(arr[i])
       }
   }
   return quickSort(left).concat([middleValue], quickSort(right));
};
quickSort([1,5,3,2,4,6,8,9])
```

Qusetion：
when write like this, there is an error" RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

> for(let i = 0; i < len; i++)

but it works like this,

> for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)

why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is mutating operation. After

```js
let middleValue = arr.splice(idx, 1)[0];
```

your actual `arr.length` is decreased by one. That leads to algorithm convergence. While `len` still holds the old full length value.